# A word to describe a person who is in top/winning bracket of a competitive game

Tags: american-english, british-english

I am looking for a word that would describe a player who is, for example, in a TOP 10 chart and is eligible for a prize. That means that if he would suddenly lose his/her position and get ranked 11 or lower, he/she could no longer be called that way, since that player is not one of the victors.

I'll give a small example of use:

My games: 41 <-- this is total amount of games the player takes part in
*Games where I hold a top rank*: 11 <-- this is where need help

I would like this to be explained in 1-2 words and I was wondering if such word already exists.
If at all possible I would like to use international or simple english.

Comment: Are you looking for a synonym for 'top player'?

Comment: @Josh61 more of a word or couple of words to say "games where I'm the top player". Hopefully it makes sense, English isn't my first language.

Comment: Stars of basket, football, car racing etc.

Comment: @Josh61 so writing "Starts of games" would mean games where the player is one of the victors? If so, please put that as an answer.

Comment: **Prize Candidate** or **Award Candidate**

Comment: I remember in our university hostels, we used to call such people 'James Bond', as in that particular area :P that guy really knows his game whatever he be involved in. Be it academics, a sport or robotics or any other such categories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Top Ranked" while not one word would usually suffice.

```
adjective:
considered to be the best or among the best   ⇒ "the top-ranked amateur in France"
```

http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/top-ranked

Comment: You know, "means that if he would suddenly lose his/her position and get ranked 11 or lower, he/she could no longer be called that way"

Answer (score 0):

"Games that I'm highly ranked in" comes to mind.

Comment: Sorry, but that's very long. I wanted that sentence in one word :)

Comment: @CreativeMagic What you ask of is probably impossible.

Answer (score 0):

The word "finalist" means someone who has survived earlier challenges and is now competing for the top prize.  In your example, there would be ten finalists.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is

"Top-ten player."

it's literally that simple.

"means that if he would suddenly lose his/her position and get ranked 11 or lower, he/she could no longer be called that way" ... so, **top-ten player**.  It's that simple.